# I cannot see my OpenVPN TAP adapters in Hyper-V external switch bridging

Tags: virtualization, openvpn, hyper-v, bridge, tap

I cannot see my OpenVPN TAP adapters in Hyper-V external switch bridging. Is it even supported in Hyper-V? I do not see any documentation where it says it is either supported or not. I have Windows 11 Enterprise by the way.

I can however see it in other virtualization software such as Virtualbox.